# Android Progressbar and thread optimization

Tags: android, multithreading, android-progressbar

i am working on a progressBar. The idea of my project is that the user is able to start/resume the progression of the progressBar with one button and to reset it if needed with another button (like a stopwatch).
After reading some topics about how to handle its visual progression with a thread, I wanted to know if I am doing it the right way and if my code could be improve. I want to correctly interrupt or resume the thread. Thank you for your help.

Here my Main Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.progbar_horiz);

    pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_horiz);
    textField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texttime);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ring_Start);
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ring_Stop);
    Drawable draw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress_bar);
    pbar.setProgressDrawable(draw);
    maxBar = pbar.getMax();

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(startButton.getText() == "Start") {
                pbar.setProgress(0);
                progress = 0;
                startButton.setText("Pause");
                myThread = new ProgressThread();
                myThread.start();
            } else {
                if (startButton.getText() == "Pause") {
                    startButton.setText("Resume");
                    myThread.interrupt();
                } else {
                    startButton.setText("Pause");
                    myThread = null;
                    myThread = new ProgressThread();
                    myThread.start();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(myThread != null) {
                myThread.interrupt();
                pbar.setProgress(0);
                progress = 0;
                startButton.setText("Start");
            }
        }
    });
}

private class ProgressThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!this.isInterrupted() && progress < maxBar) {
            try { Thread.sleep(DELAY_MS);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            progress += 1;

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pbar.setProgress(progress);
                    if (progress == maxBar) {
                        startButton.setText("Start");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

}